# Access to many websites under OS X Server on port 80

Tags: macos, server.app, apache, websites

I've installed two web applications (Jenkins and Redmine) on my OS X Mavericks Server. Both are available in local network from other computers as:

- myserver.local:8080 (Jenkins)
- myserver.local:8081/redmine (Redmine installed from Bitnami)

Also I redirect to domains to my public IP:

- ci.mydomain.com
- pm.mydomain.com

At this moment I'm able to get access to my web applications from the Internet in this way:

- ci.mydomain.com:8080 (Jenkins)
- pm.mydomain.com:8081 (Redmine)

Now I want to change this configuration to more friendly form which allow to get access to this applications directly by enter only domains like:

- ci.mydomain.com
- pm.mydomain.com

Do you have any suggestion what and where should I change in my server configuration to get this result (access many sites on default 80 port)?

Answer (score 1):

You need a web server in front of your sites, acting as a proxy.

With Apache web server, use the [mod_proxy module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) (I think on Apache you'll need to enable the module from httpd.conf, by uncommenting the line starting with `LoadModule proxy_http_module`).

If you prefer nginx, use the [http_proxy module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html).

Both are pretty much straight forward to configure.